# Typecasting back int values(0-255) stored in char* gives negative values

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#define TRANSFORMS 4
#define BLOCK 4
using namespace std;
char* img=new char[128*128*TRANSFORMS];
int main(){
ifstream File;
File.open("ficdata");
int isize=128*TRANSFORMS*128;
int inc=TRANSFORMS*128;
int jsize=128*TRANSFORMS;
int i=0,j=0,temp;
while(!File.eof())
{
    File>>temp;
    img[i+j]=temp;
    j+=TRANSFORMS;
    if(j==jsize){
        j=0;
        i+=inc;
    }
    if(i==isize){
        break;
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<isize;i+=inc){
    for(int j=0;j<jsize;j+=TRANSFORMS){
        cout<<(int)img[i+j]<<" ";
    }
}
}
```

In the above code snippet the file contains 128*128 values which are between 0-255.When I try to typecast the values back to int and print them I get some values as positive and some values as negative.Why does that happen?The int values are getting stored properly and the problem occurs only when typecasting them back.

Comment: Why are you using `new` to allocate a static, global array?

Comment: [`while(!File.eof())` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: Please read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: The `File>>temp;` will skip whitespace, which is probably not what you want for a binary file, since the stream does not distinguish between a whitespace character and a binary byte of the same value.

Answer (score 1):

`char` has implementation-defined signedness. On some platforms it has the same range as `unsigned char` (usually 0 .. 255), on other platforms it has the same range as `signed char` (usually -128 .. 127).

Apparently on your system it is signed, so storing values above 127 results in negative numbers. You can fix this by changing `img` to `unsigned char`.

Also, there's no reason I can see for `img` to be allocated dynamically. You could just do

```
unsigned char img[128*128*TRANSFORMS];
```